# Error al crear un nuevo nombre de columna con summarise reutilizando un cálculo de otra columna recién calculada con n()

Tags: r, group-by, tidyverse, summarise

tengo un problema con el siguiente :

```
   t2 = t1 %>% group_by(bd_int[1], Opcion) %>% 
    summarise("Subtotal" = n(), "Porciento" = (Subtotal/obs*100))
```

obs lo he calculado anteriormente:

```
obs = bd_int %>% summarise(n())
```

este código está en la misma función. El problema es que el título de la segunda columna que especifico en el `summarise` no es `"Porciento"`, sino que genera `"Porciento$n()"`. Como si "arrastrara" para su denominación el cómo se calcula `Subtotal`, con su asignación de `n()`, en lugar de dejar la etiqueta de la nueva variable tal cual la indico en el entrecomillado.

La función completa es la siguiente:

```
totales_1vble_RU <- function(df_datos, df_enunciados, vble, Opciones) {
  bd_int = df_datos %>% select(all_of(vble))
  obs = bd_int %>% summarise(n())
  if (is_tibble(Opciones)) {
    Opciones = as.character(Opciones)
  }
  condiciones = purrr::imap(Opciones, ~quo(bd_int == !!.y ~!!.x))
  t1 = bd_int %>% mutate(Opcion = case_when(!!!condiciones))
   t2 = t1 %>% group_by(bd_int[1], Opcion) %>% 
    summarise("Subtotal" = n(), "Porciento" = (Subtotal/obs*100))
  lt = length(t2[[1]])
  lo = length(Opciones)
  # si no están todos los valores posibles, rellenamos con huecos
  if (lt < lo) {
    t3 = tibble::tibble("{vble}" := 1:lo, Opciones, Subtotal = 0, Porciento = 0.0)
    for (i in 1:(lt)) {
      t3[as.numeric(t2[i,1]),3] = as.numeric(t2[i,3])
      t3[as.numeric(t2[i,1]),4] = t2[i,3]/obs*100
    }
    return (t3)
  }
  return(t2)
}
```

El extraño comportamiento está en que si desde el terminal realizo esto:

```
t_v16_RU = totales_1vble_RU(t_v16, enunciados_encuesta, "V16", gradacion_SiNo)
colnames(t_v16_RU)
```

El resultado mostrado es correcto:

```
[1] "V16"       "Opcion"    "Subtotal"  "Porciento"
```

Sin embargo en la visualización de t_v16_RU:

```
>t_v16_RU
# A tibble: 2 × 4
# Groups:   V16 [2]
    V16 Opcion Subtotal Porciento$`n()`
  <int> <chr>     <int>           <dbl>
1     1 Sí           56           93.3 
2     2 No            4            6.67
```

Otro elemento extraño es el hecho de que al intentar generar un fichero de hoja de cálculo con t_v16_RU, genera un error:

```
> write.xlsx(t_v16_RU, "t_v16_RU.xlsx")
Error in is.nan(tmp) : default method not implemented for type 'list'
```

Lo cual no ocurre al generar un fichero con el tibble que se utiliza para su cálculo, t_v16:

```
> t_v16
# A tibble: 60 × 3
    V161  V162   V16
   <dbl> <dbl> <int>
 1     1     0     1
 2     1     0     1
 3     1     0     1
 4     1     0     1
 5     1     0     1
 6     1     0     1
 7     0     1     2
 8     1     0     1
 9     0     1     2
10     1     0     1
# … with 50 more rows
```

Es una suposición el que considere que ese nombre de columna anómala es el que está provocando ese error. En relación a cómo se provoca dicho error es por lo que lo relaciono con el `summarise`. Es el único caso donde el uso de `summarise` provoca este comportamiento. En otras ocasiones al hacer algo similar ha generado correctamente el nombre de la nueva columna calculada. Estoy trabajando sobre `RStudio`.
Saludos y gracias

Comment: ¿Que representa `bd_int[1]` y qué relación tiene con `t1`?

Comment: Buenas, ese código está en la función que acabo de añadir completamente a la pregunta formulada.

Comment: He añadido más elementos para intentar encontrar dónde está el problema. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo acabo de solucionar: el error no estaba en el summarise, sino que venía arrastrado del cálculo de `obs`:

```
obs = bd_int %>% summarise(n())
```

generaba un tibble y al hacer la división para calcular el porcentaje, generaba ese nombre extraño en la columna, aunque sí hiciera bien el cálculo. La cuestión entonces ha quedado que he usado directamente una referencia al valor del tibble que generaba `obs[[1]]`:

```
  t1 = bd_int %>% mutate(Opcion = case_when(!!!condiciones)) %>%
    group_by(bd_int[1], Opcion) %>%
    summarise(Subtotal = n(), "%" = Subtotal/**obs[[1]]**)
```